# Using push_back on a vector of strings - C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, push-back

I am trying to use `push_back` on a vector of strings in C++. How can I push a single character on to the vector? Currently, I have tried the following, all without success:

1. Initialized a string (tried to) with the character.

Code

```
string str(main_string[0]);  
vector_string.push_back(str);
```

2. Tried to invoke strcpy and thus copy contents. Const-ness seems to get in the way.

Code

```
string str;  
strcpy(main_string[0], str.c_str());  
vector_string.push_back(str);
```

Any more suggestions/ideas are most welcome.

Edit: The error logs are as follows:

```
test_push.C: In function ‘void test_push(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, std::string)’:
test_push.C:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:220: note: candidates are: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type, _CharT, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:213: note:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:206: note:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:194: note:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type, typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:184: note:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type, typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:170: note:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:178: note:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/basic_string.h:2147: note:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
test_push.C:61: error: conversion from ‘char’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string’ requested
test_push:90: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:220: note: candidates are: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type, _CharT, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:213: note:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:206: note:                 std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
```

More info: In this function, either the entire string or just the first letter is pushed in to the vector based on its contents. So, in a way, I am looking for some function that converts a `char` into a C++ style `std::string` (to make it acceptable to a vector).

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: What are the errors you are actually getting? Also, in the second one, are you trying to copy str into main_string[0] or vice versa?

Comment: string is in turn a vector of characters. Why do you want to create a vector with string ( but only one character)?

Comment: Actually your problem is, initializing a string with one character.

Comment: @quasiverse: added more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no need for strcpy for a single character.

```
string str ("x");
str[0] = main_string[0]; 
vector_string.push_back(str);
```

Comment: Or even just `string str; str += main_string[0];`.

Comment: or `string str (main_string, 0, 1);`  There's a lot of ways to do this!

Answer (score 7):

You can also initialize with one character like this.

```
string str(1,main_string[0]);  
vector_string.push_back(str);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add the character directly via an appropriate string constructor:

```
vector_string.push_back(string(1, main_string[0]));
```

**EDIT:** Removed alternate solution after realising it duplicates [@Tim's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322522/using-push-back-on-a-vector-of-strings-c/5322604#5322604).